# mysql clculate daily kWh consumption from solar inverter

Tags: mysql

i read data from solar inverter and store it into mysql database

the table has 2 fields dtime records the date and time and AC_Output_Apparent_Power records the current load in Watts.

what i need is to calculate **total daily wattage consumption** like this (example):

```
date        kWh
2018-10-24  1.3
2018-10-10 0.700
2018-10-09 2.2
```

and so on...

i tried:

```
SELECT date(dtime),hour(dtime),((avg(AC_Output_Apparent_Power) *1)/1000) as kWh 
FROM `logs` 
WHERE AC_Output_Apparent_Power > 0 
GROUP by date(dtime),hour(dtime) 
order by dtime desc
```

and the result is hourly consumption:

```
date       hour     kWh     
2018-10-25  2   0.20880952
2018-10-25  1   0.23985294
2018-10-24  18  0.29619231
2018-10-23  6   0.11400000
2018-10-22  6   0.13800000
2018-10-22  2   0.13800000
2018-10-18  1   0.13800000
2018-10-16  10  0.09200000
2018-10-15  13  0.09100000
2018-10-14  21  0.13800000
2018-10-13  22  0.13700000
2018-10-13  8   0.09200000
2018-10-12  6   0.18966667
2018-10-12  5   0.17800000
2018-10-12  4   0.13800000
2018-10-10  15  0.25100000
2018-10-10  14  0.61285714
2018-10-09  18  0.13800000
2018-10-09  1   0.15150000
2018-10-04  5   0.14728947
2018-10-04  4   0.15062500
2018-10-04  3   0.14927778
2018-10-04  2   0.14958974
2018-10-04  1   0.14726744
2018-10-04  0   0.14886207
```

the mysql table has these values.

Note: as you see the data is not read regularly as i am testing

```
SELECT dtime,AC_Output_Apparent_Power FROM `logs` WHERE AC_Output_Apparent_Power > 0 order by dtime desc 


dtime                  AC_Output_Apparent_Power     
2018-10-24 18:20:25     152
2018-10-24 18:20:02     174
2018-10-24 18:19:50     174
2018-10-24 18:19:38     174
2018-10-24 18:19:26     173
2018-10-24 18:19:03     174
2018-10-24 18:18:51     154
2018-10-24 18:18:04     174
2018-10-24 18:17:53     175
2018-10-24 18:17:46     174
2018-10-24 18:17:29     175
2018-10-24 18:17:17     175
2018-10-24 18:17:05     174
2018-10-24 18:16:53     174
2018-10-24 18:16:48     174
2018-10-24 18:16:18     816
2018-10-24 18:15:54     174
2018-10-24 18:15:42     174
2018-10-24 18:15:30     852
2018-10-24 18:15:18     173
2018-10-24 18:15:07     174
2018-10-24 18:14:55     1084
2018-10-24 18:14:32     174
2018-10-24 18:14:26     173
2018-10-24 18:13:33     176
2018-10-24 18:13:21     152
2018-10-24 18:13:09     175
2018-10-24 18:12:58     174
2018-10-24 18:12:47     939
2018-10-24 18:12:37     174
2018-10-24 18:12:30     175
2018-10-24 18:11:48     815
2018-10-24 18:11:01     880
2018-10-24 18:10:49     924
2018-10-24 18:10:37     753
2018-10-24 18:10:13     154
2018-10-24 18:10:01     176
2018-10-24 18:09:50     174
2018-10-24 18:09:38     175
2018-10-24 18:09:26     176
2018-10-24 18:09:15     176
2018-10-24 18:09:03     176
2018-10-24 18:08:52     154
2018-10-24 18:08:40     176
2018-10-24 18:08:27     176
2018-10-24 18:08:16     176
2018-10-24 18:08:04     928
2018-10-24 18:07:52     176
2018-10-24 18:07:41     177
2018-10-24 18:07:29     176
2018-10-24 18:07:17     177
2018-10-24 18:06:54     178
2018-10-23 06:06:12     114
2018-10-22 06:49:01     138
2018-10-22 02:00:29     138
2018-10-18 01:47:54     138
2018-10-16 10:04:14     92
2018-10-15 13:59:27     91
2018-10-14 21:59:44     138
2018-10-13 22:01:48     137
2018-10-13 08:37:37     92
2018-10-13 08:02:43     92
2018-10-12 06:05:53     190
2018-10-12 06:05:41     190
2018-10-12 06:03:08     189
2018-10-12 05:58:59     166
2018-10-12 05:58:12     190
2018-10-12 04:31:56     138
2018-10-10 15:08:31     241
2018-10-10 15:06:34     370
2018-10-10 15:05:35     239
2018-10-10 15:03:02     154
2018-10-10 14:58:41     864
2018-10-10 14:58:16     456
2018-10-10 14:58:07     415
2018-10-10 14:57:53     545
2018-10-10 14:57:41     714
2018-10-10 14:56:43     1300
2018-10-10 14:56:22     949
2018-10-10 14:55:55     608
2018-10-10 14:55:45     522
2018-10-10 14:54:45     415
2018-10-10 14:54:34     431
2018-10-10 14:54:10     503
2018-10-10 14:53:47     506
2018-10-10 14:53:35     438
2018-10-10 14:53:23     417
2018-10-10 14:45:43     874
2018-10-10 14:45:31     442
2018-10-10 14:45:08     710
2018-10-10 14:44:19     421
2018-10-10 14:44:07     604
2018-10-10 14:40:23     736
2018-10-09 18:05:58     138
2018-10-09 01:05:55     153
2018-10-09 01:05:29     153
2018-10-09 01:05:04     152
2018-10-09 01:04:40     151
2018-10-09 01:04:13     151
2018-10-09 01:03:47     152
```

**Watts to kWh calculation**
The energy E in kilowatt-hours (kWh) is equal to the power P in watts (W),
times the time period t in hours (hr) divided by 1000:

> E(kWh) = P(W) × t(hr) / 1000

How to calculate **total daily wattage consumption** not hourly.

any suggestions are welcomed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: And the question is ... ???

Comment: How to calculate total daily wattage consumption not hourly? my code do hourly.

Comment: `GROUP by date(dtime)`   just remove second group by filed  `hour(dtime)`

Comment: the problem is here: ((avg(AC_Output_Apparent_Power) *1)/1000) as kWh  the 1 is for one hour, i need to know total hours. this code works for hourly bases not daily. or if there any other solution for calculating the wattage is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what exactly you want to get.

But here is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d5bef/6

```
SELECT date(dtime),(SUM(AC_Output_Apparent_Power)/1000) as kW
FROM `logs` 
WHERE AC_Output_Apparent_Power > 0 
GROUP by date(dtime)
order by dtime desc ;
```

Please provide expected result set.

Comment: this gives wrong results:  on day 2018-10-24   kWh = 15.402
it's not correct. 

on 2018-10-24 18:06:54    first read is : 178 watt
on 2018-10-24 18:20:25    last read is: 152 watt

the diff is 15 miuntes , and it's worng that during 15 minutes the power consumption is 15.402 kWH???

Comment: @MohammedAhmed you have wrong logic in your mind. **Consumption** is not measured by kWh but by kW - that is what my query does. Your attempt to get average kWh is kind wrong from my point of view. So if you want you can always divide it to 24 to get it per hour. Sorry but I'll not spend time on that weird calculations. It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00') AS `time`,
       AVG(value / 1000) as "value",
       name as "metric" -- phase / line
FROM `power` 
WHERE name IN ("PhaseA_Energy", "PhaseB_Energy", "PhaseC_Energy")
AND $__timeFilter(timestamp)
GROUP BY date_format( timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H' ), name
```